# Oracle 12c SYSTEM user locked out

Tags: oracle, windows, oracle-12c

We have a development Oracle 12c database and the SYSTEM user account is locked out for one of the SID's (works fine with another SID). When I try to do a `conn SID / as sysdba` it keeps connecting me to another SID that's idle. So I cannot even get to the SID that has the locked account.

Any ideas on how to connect to the SID that has the locked SYSTEM account so I can unlock and reset the password?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. This is on a Windows system. When I do connect as 'sqlplus / as sysdba' it default logs me into the other instance. I'll look at trying to force the environment to push me to the other instance and see if that works.

Comment: Is this a pluggable database ? If not, you just need to set your environment correct. There's no "default" SID, there often is a chaos of environment variables and related stuff, but as stated, in a chaos way. Often the first database installed, but not necessarily. So, question : how do you set your environment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, figured it out with the comments from my original question. Steps I used to connect to the correct instance and get the account unlocked and password reset.

1. Connect to the correct SID/instance off the top. Example:

   `c:\sqlplus SYSTEM/<Password>@<service name>` --> this can be found in the tnsnames.ora file
2. I then verified I was in the correct instance:

   `SQL>select instance_name, status from v$instance;`
3. From there I was able to unlock the user and reset their password:

   `SQL>alter user <USERNAME> account UNLOCK;`

   `SQL>alter user <USERNAME> identified by <PASSWORD>;`

My problem intially was that I was just trying to connect using `sqlplus / as sysdba` and it wasn't putting me in the correct instance.

Hopefully this will be helpful to other Oracle devs and rookie DBA's (I'm a rookie in this since we have a dev instance for some client work and it rarely gets touched).

Comment: set ORACLE_SID=<fancy instance> then
sqlplus / as sysdba, would do the job as well